# I cannot see the .csv file I have saved using Spark & Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to save into a .csv file the result of the query I made using SQL and Parquet, from a DataFrame.

This is how I wrote my query:

[image: This his how I query]

And this is how I save the data:

[image]

But the supposed .csv file output is no where to be seen:

[image]

Comment: can you make sure the `df.select().filter() ` actually contains data before writing?

Comment: That’s because it’s been saved on HDFS.

Comment: I do apologise for being somewhat ignorant. But can you give me hints on how do I access the data in HDFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding **file:///home/hadoop/apr2.csv.gz** instead of **/home/hadoop.apr2.csv**. You can refer to the following code snippet available on the databricks' spark-csv module present on [Github Spark CSV](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
    .load("cars.csv")

val selectedData = df.select("year", "model")
selectedData.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
    .save("newcars.csv.gz")
```

As for the prefix **file:///** we usually add it if we want to perform any read or write operation from local filesystem instead of HDFS.

Comment: Do you think this method of writing it can handle 1,500+ rows? But the "file:///" part of your suggestion has been very insightful for me, it made me understand that I have to save it locally and not on Hadoop File System. Thank you!

Comment: 1500+ rows should not be an issue unless you use `coalesce()`, which would make on humongous CSV. This would save the csv file in several parts like part0001.csv,part0002.csv and so on.

Comment: Hi! As of now I have solved the problem by just using `coalesce()` to make the output become just one super nice single _.csv_ file. Upvoted

Answer (score 2):

To add dependency, start your spark shell using following command:

**spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0**

Read your paraquet file using:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("file:///home/mugdha/users.parquet")
```

Apply filter, select operations:

```
val filteredDF = df.select("name","favorite_color")
```

To save filteredDF, you can use following code:

```
filteredDF.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("file:///home/mugdha/testSave")
```

Inside testSave folder, you can check out your stored csv.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your suggestion, it seems to be working, but I don't think it can handle 1,500+ rows. Do you think it can? But if not, is it logical to split the output to several sequential .csv files?

Comment: Surely, It can handle 1500+ rows.

Comment: You can use repartition as 'filteredDF.repartition(num_partitions)write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("file:///home/mugdha/testSave")'